# rails if statement in controller - checking nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, null

I have an if statement in my update action in one of my controllers. It looks like this:

```
if !@bid.attributes.values.include?(nil)
    build(@bid.id)
end
```

I am checking to see if there are any nil valued attributes in my Bid object before building a bid report. I know the build method works fine because it builds a report when not wrapped in the if statement. When it is wrapped in this if statement, it doesn't run. I have checked to make sure that there are no nil values in the object. I went into the rails console and all attributes have non-nil values. In addition, I am able to check this in the views to confirm that there are no nil values.

I have also tried writing as:

```
build(@bid.id) unless @bid.attributes.values.include?(nil)
```

and a couple other variations. None are allowing the build to run.

Comment: what says `p @bid.attributes.values.include?(nil)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems fine, I'm betting it's your data that's the problem instead.  Mostly likely, assuming this an active record instance, the attribute is `id` which will be `nil` until the new record gets saved.

What do you get in the terminal when you add this line right before your `if`?

```
puts @bid.attributes.to_yaml
```

You should be able to see what has values and what does not. And I'm pretty sure at least one of those values is `nil`.

---

I would recommend being more explicit about exactly which fields are required. And this is exactly what validations are for.

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :name, presence: true
end
```

You explicitly validate each field so that when it's absent you get a very specific error message about why: "Person name can't be blank." So instead of wondering why it wont save, you get told why at the point it fails to save.